# Текст надписи при нажатии кнопки не меняется

Tags: python, kivy

Почему не текст надписи при нажатии кнопки не меняется. Объясните пожалуйста, что я сделал не так

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

activity = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: lbl_time_now
        text: '00'
        font_size: 60
    Button:
        text: 'Start'
        font_size: 60
        on_press: app.something
    '''

class TimeCountApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(activity)

    def something(self, instance):
        self.lbl_time_now.text = '01'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TimeCountApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке `on_press: app.something` вы забыли поставить скобки, таким образом не вызывая функцию.

Я поставил скобки (`on_press: app.something()`) и передал в эту функцию аргументом **родителя этих элементов**, чтобы после получить **Label** и поменять в нём текст. Также, я добавил lbl_time_now в kv-строку, чтобы элемент lbl_time_now отображался в ids.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

activity = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    lbl_time_now: lbl_time_now
    Label:
        id: lbl_time_now
        text: '00'
        font_size: 60
    Button:
        text: 'Start'
        font_size: 60
        on_press: app.something(self.parent)
    '''

class TimeCountApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(activity)

    def something(self, root):
        root.ids.lbl_time_now.text = '01'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TimeCountApp().run()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!